# How to COPY Cassandra data from yesterday to csv

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I want to copy all the data of one Cassandra node from yesterday (midnight to midnight) into a csv file.

Is there a nice solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to copy or export data from Cassandra. If you want a resulting csv file you will have to use the CQL COPY command. COPY TO exports data from a table into a csv file

```
COPY table_name [( column_list )]
TO 'file_name'[, 'file2_name', ...] | STDOUT
[WITH option = 'value' [AND ...]]
```

You can read more about how to use the COPY TO command [HERE](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCopy.html)

You could also use sstabledump but you end up with a json file. You can read about that option [HERE](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/ToolsSSTabledump.html)

Hope that helps, 
Pat

Comment: Except that `COPY` cannot enforce logic around filtering the result set, as the OP mentioned that they wanted all data added *yesterday.* . Plus, he asked to copy data from *one* node, which involves querying token ranges to ensure that you're hitting only a specific node.